# UITextView text Disappears

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

I am using `UITextView` to display the NSAttributedString (Which Contains `NSTextAttachment` and `HTML` tables using `NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType`).

When I scrolling the `UITextView` at half of the screen the texts are disappearing. [image]
**Can any one explain how it happens? and how to resolve it?**

```
UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc]init];
textView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1024);
textView.editable = NO;
textView.selectable = NO;
textView.attributedText = attributedString; //My AttributedSting
[self.view addSubview:textView];
```

Comment: Can you please tell me what is delegate? means is it AppDelegate object?

Comment: @AjayGabani It's `NSMutableAttributedString`

Comment: Look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20412563/in-my-programmatically-instantiated-uitextview-initialized-with-nstextcontainer.

Comment: @ninjaproger I have tried that. The result is same :(

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because of incorrect size of the textview frame. Change the background colour of the textview to see if the frame has been set appropriately.

Comment: The frame is `CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1024);` , and I have created only one UITextView only. Then how it will be incorrect size of frame?

Comment: Have you take into account the height of the nav bar on top?

Comment: Yes. I added height of navigation bar also. My TexView texts are hidden from halfway.

Answer (score 0):

Try making sure no constraints are created automatically by adding:

```
[textView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
```

Ideally you would be best to use constraints so that the text view is pinned on its leading edge and trailing edge to the containing view and on its bottom edge and top edge to the bottom layout guide and top layout guide respectively.

Comment: Where are you adding the text view in your code? Also it might be worth making the background color red say and printing out the frame in `viewDidAppear` to see what actual frame it is using. Also have you added any other views which could be covering the bottom of the screen?

Comment: You could also try using the 3D exploded view in the simulator which will show you the view layers in depth order. If you have not used this before, it is activated by pressing the symbol on the debugger when running which looks like a cross made from two rectangles: one over the other. The exploded view will show you where all your views are.

Comment: You understands my question wrongly. The texts are showing full screen initially. When I scrolling to end of the document the text are disappearing in half way mark. You can see it in my screenshot, where the scroll bar is visibile

Comment: Does the scroll bar go all the way to the bottom or just half way?

Comment: It goes all the way to the bottom

Comment: I noticed on a few sites that some code sets scrolling to NO, then sets the attributed text, then sets scrolling to YES. So: `textView.scrollEnabled = NO; textView.attributedText = attributedString; textView.scrollEnabled = YES;`

Comment: Perhaps also try adding it as a subview "before" you set the text and other properties.

Comment: Both are not working. When I tried this `textView.scrollEnabled = NO; textView.attributedText = attributedString; textView.scrollEnabled = YES; ` the textview not scrolling

Comment: This looks similar to you issue. Worth a look. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16836707/uitextview-text-cut-off-when-there-is-a-large-amount-of-text